# unable to run command prompt using java

Tags: java, windows

I'm just trying to open a command prompt window using java program (in eclipse). When i run pgm as below, it's not showing any message

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");
```

But when i try to open internet explorer using below line

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iexplore");
```

It's throwing below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: iexplore error=2
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at dev.petrofac.ChangeFilePermission.main(ChangeFilePermission.java:17)
```

Comment: If it isn't throwing an error, doesn't that mean it's working?

Comment: It's not opening command prompt window so i guess it's not working

Comment: try `iexplore.exe`, see http://about-java-programming.blogspot.com/2007/02/javaioioexception-createprocess.html

Comment: yeh i tried iexplore.exe but it's throwing same error. also for cmd i tried C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe but no use :(

Comment: just to be sure, you have put double escape characters in string literal of the full command path ? (i.e. `cmd = "C:\\WINDOWS\\...")

Comment: yeh i put like   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe");
still it's not showing any message

Comment: Sorry for the curiosity, but for what reason would you like to open the command prompt from Java?

Comment: does it work when you run it standalone (e.g. from the command prompt) rather than from inside Eclipse ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact is that you *are starting cmd*. Just because you can't see it doesn't mean it doesn't start.

If you want to see the output from the application, you need to get the outputstream
 (see [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) for details). If you want to start cmd in a new window you can execute the string "cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe" instead, as in

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe");
```

Comment: @patric wow..this seems to be working. But still not getting why it's now working when we put just cmd

Comment: @Sukumar, if you open a cmd and then type cmd you will see that nothing happens. Same for your program: the java app is run as a console application, so simply running cmd from there without /c start will not produce any effect.

Comment: @Sukumar: You can compare this with when you open cmd normally, and in that cmd window type cmd. You don't get a new window, but rather the new cmd is executed within the old cmd. The same thing happens with your exec call, but it's not brought to the foreground. The start argument is the reason why a new window appears, just as when you do it in a cmd window.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also can you pls tell me what is the significance of  "/c" in the command

Comment: @Sukamar: `/C  Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates`. Type `cmd /?` in a command prompt to read about more flags.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the file permissions for iexplore.

Allow execute privileges for all processes/users , if not set already.

Comment: For iexplore when i give whole path as   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
 it's working. But still cmd is not working though i give full path